# This expression was expected to have type 'unit' but here has type ''a []'

Tags: f#

The following code was an attempt at a recursive bubble sort in F#, where I received the error

`"This expression was expected to have type 'unit' but here has type ''a []'"`

for the middle three lines:

```
let swap i j (arr : 'a []) =
    let tmp = arr.[i]
    arr.[i] <- arr.[j]
    arr.[j] <- tmp

let rec recursiveBubbleSort i j (sequence : 'a []) =
    if i = sequence.Length then sequence //error
    elif j = sequence.Length then recursiveBubbleSort (i+1) 0 sequence //error
    elif sequence.[i] > sequence.[j] then swap i j sequence //error
    recursiveBubbleSort i (j+1) sequence
```

This is really puzzling me, as all of the resources I have found haven't sufficiently explained or implied why this is actually occurring. Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted to write:

```
let rec recursiveBubbleSort i j (sequence : 'a []) =
    if i = sequence.Length then sequence
    elif j = sequence.Length then recursiveBubbleSort (i+1) 0 sequence 
    else
        if sequence.[i] > sequence.[j] then swap i j sequence |> ignore 
        recursiveBubbleSort i (j+1) sequence
```

So, the last `elif` you wrote has to be an `else`, within that `else` there is another `if` that checks whether to perform the swap or not.

All `if` .. `then`, including `elif` or not, must end with an `else` unless it's a `unit` expression (as the call to `swap`).

That's why you were getting that error.

Finally note that your comparison is inverted, you will sort the list in descending order.

Comment: Excellent - you legend! Thanks!